# Cannot read the visible attribute of a menuitem properly

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0

In the following code, the IF statement:

```
If mnuSubItem1.Visible = False And mnuSubItem2.Visible = False Then
    mnuMainMenuItem.Visible = False
End If
```

Always results as true, regardless of the visible states of subitem1 and subitem2?
`If mnuSubItem1.visible = true and mnuSubItem2.visible = false` the code within the `IF` statement still executes.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You mean even if any of the two equals to true?

Comment: I updated the question a little more informative.
The control is System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip
The mnuMainMenuItem is top-level and the Subs are beneath it.

Comment: Are this .NET standard Controls? Or any special?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using this Items as sub menu items, like this:

mnuMainMenuItem -> mnuSubItem1 & mnuSubItem2

When mnuMainMenuItem is closed, mnuSubItem1 & 2 are not visible. So the program decide to execute the if statement.

[image: Visible = False]

[image: Visible = True]

Use this code to reach your goal:

```
mnuMainMenuItem.ShowDropDown()
If mnuSubItem1.Visible = False And mnuSubItem2.Visible = False Then
    mnuMainMenuItem.Visible = False
End If
mnuMainMenuItem.HideDropDown()
```

Comment: you are absolutely correct.  I instead of your solution, used the .enabled = false with the .visible=false and checked the status using the .enabled attribute.  Thank you for your quick answer!  Wish I could vote you up, but I am still a newb and it won't let me.. :/

Comment: Nice to hear that i can help you :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% clear here what the intent of that statement is — you may have made a common logic error. But I can present two options that might help. Try this:

```
If Not mnuSubItem1.Visible AndAlso Not mnuSubItem2.Visible Then
    mnuMainMenuItem.Visible = False
End If
```

or this:

```
If Not mnuSubItem1.Visible OrElse Not mnuSubItem2.Visible Then
    mnuMainMenuItem.Visible = False
End If
```

Based on the edit, we could try inverse, and even eliminate the IF entirely:

```
mnuMainMenuItem.Visible = mnuSubItem1.Visible OrElse mnuSubItem2.Visible
```

Comment: I have tried both your solutions, and still the IF computes TRUE (even though both subitems are set to visible) and executes the "mnuMainMenuItem.Visible = False" statement.

Comment: The intent is to make the top level menuitem not visible if there are no visible menuitems below it.

Comment: @RonB added a new option. This completely replaces the entire If block. If this doesn't work, you need to put a breakpoint or logging code in there, because your SubItem values are _not_ what you think they are. You'll need to track down when they did (or did not) change.

Comment: The values of visible of the subitems are not true until the menu is clicked on (activated and displayed) as Niklas B. said. therefore I changed my tactics, and went with .enabled since the value is constant whether or not it is visible. but thanks anyways Joel :)